# Xamarin forms designing for multiple resolutions

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How can we design according to various resolutions in Xamarin forms application. I have been using Viewbox control for Windows application but it is not found in Xamarin forms.My requirement is, if I set 50 px for a control , it should scale up or down according to various resolutions. Please provide some design guide lines to achieve this. I have been using Grid row definitions and column definitions, but for some cases I have to manually set height / width or padding for some controls. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe this post will help a little: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2014/07/24/Different-XAML-layouts-for-different-device-orienations-in-XamarinForms.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms does not use pixels. It uses platform specific density aware units.

> Xamarin.Forms has a philosophy of using the conventions of the
>   underlying platforms as much as possible. In accordance with this
>   philosophy, the Xamarin.Forms programmer works with sizes defined by
>   each particular platform. All sizes that the programmer encounters
>   through the Xamarin.Forms API are in these platform-specific
>   device-independent units.

That would be "points" in iOS and "dpi" on Android.

There's a whole book chapter about it (free)
https://download.xamarin.com/developer/xamarin-forms-book/BookPreview2-Ch05-Rel0203.pdf